# Replacing Matching File Names in String List

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, list

I have a main List of Files `Filelist`.The Main List Contains Full File Paths and there is a second list `copylist` it is poupulated by fetching the contents from a directory.I need to replace the File Names in `Filelist` that matches with the ones in the temporary folder,so i used the following code.

```
Filelist = new List<string>();   
//Code to Populate File List from openfiledialog   
try
{
    copylist = Directory.GetFiles(temppath + @"\mydir\");

    List<string> tempfiles = new List<string>(Filelist);
    int x = 0;
    foreach (string file in tempfiles)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < copylist .Length; i++)
        {
            if (Path.GetFileName(file) == Path.GetFileName(copylist [i]))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Removed: " + file + " \ninserted:" + copylist [i]);



                Filelist.RemoveAt(x);

                Filelist.Insert(x,copylist [i]);


            }
            x++;
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

I tested with 4 files... The File names matched when i checked manually(ie: the same file name in temp folder and in the FileList).The equality check ie:`Path.GetFileName(file) == Path.GetFileName(copylist [i])` is satisfied for just 2 files and finally only 1 file is replaced in `Filelist` even though all 4 files are present in temp folder.

What im i doing wrong.Please advice.

Comment: @MaciejLos Its a String List.Please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your program relies on the fact that positions in `tempfiles` and `Filelist` are related, and that `x` corresponds to the position of `file` in `tempfiles`. In order for this to work you need to add a `break` inside the `if`, and move `x++` to the outside loop:

```
foreach (string file in tempfiles) {
    for (int i = 0; i < copylist .Length; i++) {
        if (Path.GetFileName(file) == Path.GetFileName(copylist [i])) {
            MessageBox.Show($"Removed: {file}\ninserted:{copylist [i])}";
            Filelist.RemoveAt(x);
            Filelist.Insert(x,copylist[i]);
            break; // << Added
        }
    }
    x++; // << Moved
}
```